# Use result of stored procedure inline in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

I would like to execute a stored procedure inline, in the column definition of a `SELECT` statement, something similar to this:

```
SELECT n.Name,
       n.Key,
       (EXEC sp_GetNickname @nameKey = n.NameKey) AS Nickname
FROM Names n
```

I do not have access to modify the stored procedure (it comes from a third party system), but I know for a fact that it always selects only one row and one column (it's a scalar result).

I need to be able to call it inline because this select statement is inside a recursive CTE, something like this:

```
WITH Nicknames (Name, Key)
AS
(
    SELECT ... -- Base
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ... -- Recursive
)
```

There is also an "OUT" version of the stored procedure if that would be more useful, it would be executed as such:

```
EXEC sp_GetNicknameOut @nameKey = n.NameKey,
                       @outNickname = @theNickname OUTPUT
```

I can't add any stored procedures or functions to the database because this query is being executed from a C# application on the fly.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You cannot call a stored procedure from within a `select`.  You can call it separately, assign the value to a variable, and use the variable in the `select`.

Comment: If you can change the SP to function you can use it in query as you want.

Comment: Do you have access to view the stored procedure code? If so, I would do as @Hamlet suggests.

Comment: I can't modify or create any stored procedures, this code is being executed on the fly from a C# application, we can't "install" anything into the database. It's looking like this isn't possible to do...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can't be done as requested. 
You might be able to execute a recursive CTE without calling the procedure and save results into a temp table, then open a cursor over it, and then execute a procedure in the cursor. Not nice, but I don't see any other way.

Comment: I'm thinking that's what I'll have to do. I don't see any other way, either. Thanks!

Comment: Wasn't from me. It's the correct answer and a good alternate suggestion, so I have no idea.

Comment: Since you got a down vote, I decided to counter that with an up vote as this is a useful answer to me as well. I guess the down voter was not happy that there's no solution.

Comment: You can also use CROSS APPLY with a UDF instead of cursor

Comment: @SilentSojourner Read the question. "I can't add any stored procedures or functions to the database", OP said.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot Select from a procedure but what you can do since you know the returned number of rows and column from this procedure you can create a temp/variable table and insert into that and then use that temp table or variable table inside you other statement,

Something like this...

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp(ColName DataType)

INSERT INTO  #Temp(ColName)
EXEC sp_GetNickname @nameKey = 'value'
```

Now you can use this value inside you SELECT statement

```
SELECT n.Name,
       n.Key,
       (SELECT ColName FROM #Temp) AS Nickname
FROM Names n
```

Comment: How would you do that inside a recursive CTE?

Comment: This needs to work from within a CTE, executing the stored procedure once for each row of the SELECT statement.